# Non-matching SSH public key fingerprint in Paramiko and Boto/EC2?

Tags: python, ssh, amazon-ec2, boto, paramiko

(First a bit of context; for the actual programming question just skip the first paragraph.)

I'm one of the developers of the [GC3Pie](http://gc3pie.googlecode.com/) remote execution
framework.  GC3Pie can spin up VMs on Amazon EC2 and then connect to
them via SSH to execute commands.  Users specify a keypair (local
files) and remote keypair name, and GC3Pie will tell EC2 to authorize
the remote keypair for SSH access; if that keypair does not exist
(yet) on EC2, GC3Pie will create it by uploading the given local
public key.

We are using [Boto](https://github.com/boto/boto) to interact with EC2, and [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) for the
SSH connections.

Creation of the remote keypair works fine:

```
# context: self._conn = boto.connect_ec2(...)

with open(os.path.expanduser(self.public_key)) as fd:
    key_material = fd.read()
    imported_key = self._conn.import_key_pair(
        self.keypair_name, key_material)
    gc3libs.log.info(
        "Successfully imported key `%s` with fingerprint `%s`", ...)
```

However, before connecting to the remote VM, we verify that the
fingerprints match (code slightly abridged for readability):

```
# context: self._conn = boto.connect_ec2(...)

keypairs = dict((k.name, k) for k in self._conn.get_all_key_pairs())
# ...
# `keyfile` is the path to the *private* SSH key
pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(keyfile)
# ...
localkey_fingerprint = str.join(
    ':', (i.encode('hex') for i in pkey.get_fingerprint()))
if localkey_fingerprint != keypairs[self.keypair_name].fingerprint:
    gc3libs.log.error(
        "Keypair `%s` is present but has different fingerprint: ", ...)
```

This code used to work, but we haven't check it live for some time.
We have recently gotten a bug report stating that the keypair is
successfully uploaded, but then the fingerprints do not match.

Investigation by the reporting user shows that Paramiko appears to
compute the fingerprint like `ssh-keygen -lf $keyfile`, whereas Amazon's EC2
seems to run `openssl pkey -in $keyfile -pubout -outform DER | openssl md5 -c`.

I could not find any relevant Google hit, so I'm asking here:

- Is this a know issue?
- Is it a version issue? (e.g. we should run Paramiko at least version X.Y.Z or Boto A.B.C?)
- Are we missing some optional arguments in either the Paramiko or the Boto calls, that would influence how the fingerprints are computed?
- Or is there any other known workaround?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://blog.jbrowne.com/?p=23 ?  The bottom line is that the fingerprint AWS calculates for key pairs created in AWS is different than how most people calculate the fingerprint.  This blog post (and the comments) describe these differences and link to code to compute it the way AWS does.

Comment: @garnaat Thanks a lot! The comments and the code linked from there seem to solve the issue.  If you re-post your comment as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.